# GitHub actions "Resource not accessible by integration"

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to list the variables I have added to the repository via the github.com/[org]/[repo]/settings/variables/actions page, e.g.:
[image]

I have the following .github/workflow/test_build_deploy.yaml file:

```yaml
name: Test, Build, Deploy

on: [ push ]

permissions: write-all

jobs:
  test_build_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Export variables to env
        run: echo "GH_TOKEN=${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: List all github variables
        run: gh variable list
```

When this runs it errors with:

```
Run gh variable list
failed to get variables: HTTP 403: Resource not accessible by integration (https://api.github.com/repos/YourKuppa/run-api/actions/variables?per_page=100)
```

I have tried following [this answer's solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70435286/539490) by adding the `permissions: write-all`. And have also set "Workflow permissions" to "Read and write permissions" in both the repo's github.com/[org]/[repo]/settings/actions page setting and on the github.com/organizations/[org]/settings/actions page.
From the error message these don't appear to be working.  Any other solutions?
[image]

I know some people have reported using their PATs (Personal Access Tokens) to get this to work. I would like to avoid doing that to avoid that solution tying my personal GitHub account to their repo (as I'm only a temporary contributor to this repo). Secondly the PAT will expire in a year, where as the GitHub token that's populated on each run seems like this should be a more appropriate (robust) solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the API in a browser the error message will explain that this API needs admin:repo permission, which the actions token doesn't have.

```json
{
    "message": "Must have admin rights to Repository.",
    "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/actions/variables#list-repository-variables"
}
```

In this case, the proper solution is to rely on a [GitHub App to provide the token for your step](https://docs.github.com/en/apps/creating-github-apps/authenticating-with-a-github-app/making-authenticated-api-requests-with-a-github-app-in-a-github-actions-workflow):

```
      - name: Generate a token
        id: generate_token
        uses: actions/create-github-app-token@v1
        with:
          app-id: ${{ secrets.APP_ID }}
          private-key: ${{ secrets.APP_PRIVATE_KEY }}

      - name: Use the token
        env:
          GH_TOKEN: ${{ steps.generate_token.outputs.token }}
        run: |
          gh api octocat
```

Comment: Thank you!  I wonder why they don't seem to respect their own documentation? https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication#permissions-for-the-github_token  Perhaps accessing variables is not allowed but then it would be good to document this.

Comment: The GitHub Action token is limited in strange ways. Not sure what permissions are needed.